# Crash of Texstudio 4.7.2

Tags: tikz-pgf

Starting with version 4.6.2 of TeXStudio (updated also to 4.7.2), when compiling complex code or very simply code I have a crash with this message:

[image]

Help me!

Comment: have you submited the backtrace file to texstudio bug report as suggested by your screenshot text?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I can't access log file. The program turn around also when I have in the bottom that the progam is terminated with success...but nothing in the preview area.

Comment: sorry I can't help I don't have texstudio, but you mean there is no file at the path you show in the image?

Comment: First of all, try running the following command line: `rd /S /Q "%appdata%\texstudio"` (TeXstudio must be closed before this.). This will delete the previous TeXstudio settings, which may cause a conflict in the new version.